# Cassandra DataStax Python driver graceful shutdown logic using Celery

Tags: python, cassandra, celery

I have a problem with the signal handling in Celery. I need to be able to trigger some shutdown logic in order to gracefully disconnect from my Cassandra cluster/session (using the DataStax Python driver). I've tried two different methods of implementing the SIGTERM and SIGINT handling (see code below), assigning the teardown function to the signals. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

**celerytest.py**

```
import logging
import signal
from celery import Celery
from celery import platforms
from celery.signals import beat_init
from celery.signals import worker_process_init
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = None
session = None
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel('INFO')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"))
log.addHandler(handler)

def cassandra_init(**kwargs):
    global cluster, session
    """ Initialize a clean Cassandra connection. """
    if cluster is not None:
        log.info("Shutting down Cassandra cluster connection")
        cluster.shutdown()
    if session is not None:
        log.info("Shutting down Cassandra session connection")
        session.shutdown()    
    log.info("Initializing Cassandra connection")
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
    session = cluster.connect('test')

def cassandra_teardown(signum, frame):
    log.info("Shutting down Cassandra session connection")
    session.shutdown()
    log.info("Shutting down Cassandra cluster connection")
    cluster.shutdown()

def install_pool_process_sighandler(**kwargs):
    log.info("Installing sighandlers")
    platforms.signals["TERM"] = cassandra_teardown # DOES NOT WORK
    platforms.signals["INT"] = cassandra_teardown # DOES NOT WORK        
    #signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, cassandra_teardown) # DOES NOT WORK EITHER
    #signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, cassandra_teardown) # DOES NOT WORK EITHER


# Initialize worker context for both standard and periodic tasks.
worker_process_init.connect(cassandra_init)
worker_process_init.connect(install_pool_process_sighandler)
beat_init.connect(cassandra_init)
beat_init.connect(install_pool_process_sighandler)

app = Celery('celerytest', broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')
```

Hitting ctrl-c should trigger the *cassandra_teardown* function, but does not. What am I missing here?

**Output**

```
^C
worker: Hitting Ctrl+C again will terminate all running tasks!
worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
```